# My responsive media-query doesn't show neither mobile or desktop view

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I'm building a different view for mobile and desktop, and have problem with the limit of 500px.
When the screen has exactly a 500px width, my screen doesn't show not mobile nor desktop view.

```css
.desktop-view{
  background-color: blue;
  color : yellow
}

.mobile-view{
  background-color: yellow;
  color : blue;
}


@media (min-width: 500px) {
    section.mobile-view{
      display: none;
  }
    
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    section.desktop-view{
      display: none;
  }    
}
```

```html
<div>
      
      <section class="desktop-view">
        This is the desktop view
      </section>

      <section  class="mobile-view">
        This is the mobile view
      </section>

</div>
```

If I change one 500px by 501px, I have both lines. I feel I tried all hacky combination without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At exactly 500px, both of your media are triggered so none of your views are shown. You could `display:none` your desktop view by default and set it as `block` if the screen is larger than 500px.

```css
/* everything, or mobile only if overridden in media queries */
.mobile-view{
  background-color: yellow;
  color : blue;
}
section.desktop-view{
  display: none;
}

/* desktop */
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  section.mobile-view{
    display: none;
  }    
  section.desktop-view{
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    color : yellow
  } 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section class="desktop-view">
    This is the desktop view
  </section>
  <section  class="mobile-view">
    This is the mobile view
  </section>
</div>
```